# Change div background color automatically when color-scheme changes

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, color-scheme

I'm using 3 radio buttons to switch color-schemes (automatic depending on system, light, and dark) and setting several css variables that will change my website's colors automatically on color-scheme changes. It works on the css-controlled div, but the problem is, when I get these variables into my js, the changes don't occur automatically upon radio button presses. I may need some kind of listener, but I don't know how to do that.

Here's what I've attempted.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        --background-light : #F5F5F6;
        --background-dark  : #1D1D1F;
      }

      :root {
        color-scheme: light;
        --background : var(--background-light);
      }

      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        :root {
          color-scheme: dark;
          --background : var(--background-dark);
        }
      }

      [color-scheme="light"] {
        color-scheme : light;
        --background : var(--background-light);
      }

      [color-scheme="dark"] {
        color-scheme : dark;
        --background : var(--background-dark);
      }

      .mydivs {
        width : 100vw;
        height : 100vh;
      }

      #change-with-css {
        background : var(--background);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="color-scheme">
      <div>
        <input checked type="radio" id="auto" class="toggler" name="theme" value="auto"/>
      </div>
      <div class="color-boxes">
        <input type="radio" id="light" class="toggler" name="theme" value="light"/>
      </div>
      <div class="color-boxes">
        <input type="radio" id="dark" class="toggler" name="theme" value="dark"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div id="change-with-css" class="mydivs"></div>
    <div id="change-with-js" class="mydivs"></div>
    <script>
      const switcher = document.querySelector("#color-scheme");
      const doc = document.firstElementChild;
      const setTheme = (theme) => doc.setAttribute("color-scheme", theme);
      switcher.addEventListener("input", (e) => setTheme(e.target.value));

      const myJsDiv = document.querySelector("#change-with-js");
      const myDivBg = getComputedStyle(document.body);
      myJsDiv.style.background = myDivBg.getPropertyValue("--background");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me in vanilla js format if possible, thank you.

Comment: Your current code is working for me in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari... when I click a radio option, the page background and div background change appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the style background in js on dom loaded,but when the radio button
was pressing,you ditnt set the style again, so this is the difference between the css and js,and css always has more efficiency then js.

```html
<style>
  html {
    --background-light: #F5F5F6;
    --background-dark: #1D1D1F;
  }
  
   :root {
    color-scheme: light;
    --background: var(--background-light);
  }
  
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
     :root {
      color-scheme: dark;
      --background: var(--background-dark);
    }
  }
  
  [color-scheme="light"] {
    color-scheme: light;
    --background: var(--background-light);
  }
  
  [color-scheme="dark"] {
    color-scheme: dark;
    --background: var(--background-dark);
  }
  
  .mydivs {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  #change-with-css {
    background: var(--background);
  }
</style>
<form id="color-scheme">
  <div>
    <input checked type="radio" id="auto" class="toggler" name="theme" value="auto" />
  </div>
  <div class="color-boxes">
    <input type="radio" id="light" class="toggler" name="theme" value="light" />
  </div>
  <div class="color-boxes">
    <input type="radio" id="dark" class="toggler" name="theme" value="dark" />
  </div>
</form>
<!-- <div id="change-with-css" class="mydivs"></div> -->
<div id="change-with-js" class="mydivs"></div>
<script>
  const switcher = document.querySelector("#color-scheme");
  const doc = document.firstElementChild;
  const setTheme = (theme) => {
    doc.setAttribute("color-scheme", theme);
    const myJsDiv = document.querySelector("#change-with-js");
    const myDivBg = getComputedStyle(document.body);
    myJsDiv.style.background = myDivBg.getPropertyValue("--background");
  };
  setTheme('auto');
  switcher.addEventListener("input", (e) => setTheme(e.target.value));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. this solves a lot of my problems, since I also use, for example, Three.js, which requires me to use this approach to make sure that the canvas content updates when I click on the radio buttons.